# Случайный вектор из закрытого интервала

Tags: python, случайные-числа, numpy

С помощью `np.random.uniform(a, b, n)` можно сгенерировать вектор размера `n` с элементами из интервала `[a;b)`.

Можно ли как-то сделать то же самое, но c элементами из закрытого интервала `[a;b]`?

Comment: А смысл? Это же float, на практике существующий вариант ничем не отличается от того, что вы хотите.

Comment: @Xander отличается, текущий вариант никогда не даст `b`, а желаемый - может дать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятность получить границы интервала для нормального распределения стремится к нулю, поэтому на практике не играет роли закрытый это интервал или нет.

---

Но если очень хочется, то можно так:

```
np.random.uniform(a, b + 1e-7, n)
```

Тест:

```
In [109]: np.random.uniform(-2, 5 + 1e-7, size=10**8).max()
Out[109]: 5.000000081751573
```

Comment: В математике - да, но в программировании - не нулевая вероятность. Всё таки можно так задать интервал?

Comment: Вместо `1e-7` я прибавил `sys.float_info.epsilon`

Comment: @jojo, хорошая идея, но математику трудно обмануть ;)

Comment: `max(np.random.uniform(-2, 5 + 1e-7, size=10**8), 5)` ?

Comment: @splash58, вы пробовали это выполнить? ;)

Comment: чисто теоретическая идея